# Standard Date Format Parsing

Tags: datetime, format, powerquery

I need to convert from text to DateTime in PowerQuery the following string as an example:

Fri Mar 31 20:27:02 GMT 2023

I did a few tentatives to determine the format of the string for conversion, but I have failed:

```
DateTime.FromText([stringToConvertToDateTime], [Format = "ddd MMM-dd HH:mm:ss K yyyy", Culture ="en-US"])
```

Please help me Tks

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Could be the same format but for it to be recognized as Date Time. In the end, I'm interested in getting the Month and Year as additional columns. But i'm not able to parse the string as it is still as Text type

Answer (score 0):

So, here's what I did, assuming that you want to end up with something like "3/31/2023":

First I split up the string, then deleted the superfluous columns. I added a conditional column that translates the month name to a number. Last but not least, I reassembled what was left into one column I named "Date".

This is the M code:

```
    let
  Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcivKVPBNLFIwNlQwMrAyMrcyMFJw9w0BcoyMlWJjAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [DateTImeText = _t]),
  #"Split column by delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "DateTImeText", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" "), {"DateTImeText.1", "DateTImeText.2", "DateTImeText.3", "DateTImeText.4", "DateTImeText.5", "DateTImeText.6"}),
  #"Changed column type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split column by delimiter", {{"DateTImeText.1", type text}, {"DateTImeText.2", type text}, {"DateTImeText.3", Int64.Type}, {"DateTImeText.4", type time}, {"DateTImeText.5", type text}, {"DateTImeText.6", Int64.Type}}),
  #"Removed columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed column type", {"DateTImeText.5", "DateTImeText.4", "DateTImeText.1"}),
  #"Added custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed columns", "Month", each if [DateTImeText.2] = "Jan" then 1 else if [DateTImeText.2] = "Feb" then 2 else if [DateTImeText.2] = "Mar" then 3 else if [DateTImeText.2] = "Apr" then 4 else if [DateTImeText.2] = "May" then 5 else if [DateTImeText.2] = "Jun" then 6 else if
[DateTImeText.2] = "Jul" then 7 else if [DateTImeText.2] = "Aug" then 8 else if [DateTImeText.2] = "Sep" then 9 else if [DateTImeText.2] = "Oct" then 10 else if [DateTImeText.2] = "Nov" then 11 else 12),
  #"Removed columns 1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added custom", {"DateTImeText.2"}),
  #"Reordered columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed columns 1", {"Month", "DateTImeText.3", "DateTImeText.6"}),
  #"Inserted merged column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered columns", "Date", each Text.Combine({Text.From([Month]), Text.From([DateTImeText.3]), Text.From([DateTImeText.6])}, "/"), type text),
  #"Removed columns 2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted merged column", {"DateTImeText.6", "DateTImeText.3", "Month"}),
  #"Changed column type 1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed columns 2", {{"Date", type date}})
in
  #"Changed column type 1"
```

You can adapt this accordingly if you want the time in there as well.

PS. Sorry about the capitalized "I" in "DateTImeText", but I was too lazy to do something about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add column, custom column

```
= DateTime.FromText(Text.Replace(Text.RemoveRange([Column1], 0, 4),"GMT ",""), [Format = "MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", Culture ="en-US"])
```

[image]